# gcloud.builds.submit throws unrecognized arguments while passing env

Tags: docker, deployment, environment-variables, gcloud

I'm about to lose my mind.

I'm reading the doc: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit?hl=it#--pack
And here it says that use `--pack=[builder=BUILDER],[env=ENV],[image=IMAGE]`

```
To pass environment variables to the builder use the optional "env" key/value argument where value is a list of key values using escaping if necessary.
```

So I implement what I understand from the documentation as,

```
gcloud builds submit —pack env="CONFIGURATION=production" --tag gcr.io/web-client --timeout=15000s
```

But it throws error as:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) unrecognized arguments: env=CONFIGURATION=production
```

So what is the way to pass env variable?

Comment: It seems like the syntax should instead be this, unless you've already tried this: `--pack=env=CONFIGURATION=production`. It looks like you have an em dash (`—` vs `--`) in your command unless that was a typo when making this post.

Comment: The instructions say 'The "image" key/value must be provided'. So you need to use `--pack=env=CONFIGURATION=production,image=${SOMETHING}` and should not include `--tag=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass environment variables to the instance you can use the [`--substitutions`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions) flag. I had to use this as you can not combine `--config`, `--pack` and/or `--tag` in 1 command. (see: "At most one of these may be specified:" [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit?hl=it#--worker-pool))
This is easy to glance over and is also a problem above.

This allowed me to pass-though other environment variables.

```sh
gcloud builds submit --config ./cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions _SOME_VAR=$SOME_VAR,_SOME_OTHER_VAR='some_value'
```

You can find more info here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Note: user-defined variables have to have the `_` prefix. [Source](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions)